# Find Out A Datetime is Between Two Datetimes in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm making a blog-like platform which includes an event page. I have a model as below:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    dtime_start = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    dtime_end = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
```

Assuming I have a view called `event_main` which projects all events. However, I want to project currently active events at the top of page, highlighted. So what I need is:

1. to get exact request `datetime` of client
2. to filter `Event` instances having the request `datetime` between `dtime_start` and `dtime_end`

I thought of solutions including `for` loops and put the results in the list, however I don't really want to put model instances to a list, since there are `QuerySet`s. Is there a built-in way to do this in Django?

```
###############
# Environment #
###############
python 3.2.5
pypy 2.4.0
django 1.8.7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the request datetime of the client, you may :

1. Rely on the "Date" header (`request.META.get('HTTP_DATE')`),
2. Rely on the current date of the server and the client timezone
3. Fallback to the current date of the server

Then you can filter with common lookups as you would to for an integer:

```
Event.objects.filter(dtime_start__lte=request_datetime,
                     dtime_end__gte=request_datetime)
```

---

Note: Unless you have some specific reasons to rely on the client's date, you should probably avoid it and simply use `datetime.now()` or `timezone.now()` (both would work the same, as Django handles timezone conversion when dealing with the database). If you rely on the client's date, beware that they could temper with the `Date` header to access past or future events.

Comment: things to note: if dtime_start and dtime_end are DATETIME in the database, you need to set the start time and end time of the `request_datetime` object you pass in, otherwise you could miss Events on the `lte` and `gte` (equal) date ends.

Comment: Another note, I think it should be `__lte` and `__gte` right?

Comment: @ErayErdin, yes of course, fixed.

Comment: @warath-coder, what do you mean "the start time and end time of the `request_datetime`"? It's a datetime, not a datetime range.

Comment: I was thinking if you were trying to get full days; I miss read what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `dtime_start <= input AND dtime_end >= output`:

```
Event.objects.filter(dtime_start__lte=datetime.date(y, m, d), dtime_start__gte=datetime.date(y, m, d))
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/).